# Poor draining sandy loam soil

Tags: tomatoes, soil-amendment, watermelon

I tested my soil and discoverd it has 10% clay, 29% silt, and 59% sand. I've noticed my soil sucks when it comes to draining water (unless it's slowly raining). Water will pool on the top of the ground.

What can I add to my soil to make it drain better? I am growing watermelon and tomatoes.

Answer (score 1):

If you always dig to the same depth, and you don't grow any deep-rooted plants, over the years you can form a compacted layer that won't allow water to penetrate. Try double-digging the bed this winter and see if the problem goes away on its own.

With 59% sand, really you should be adding material to retain water, not to get rid of it. An "optimum" mix is something like 20% clay, 40% silt, 40% sand.

Of course when you double dig, you might find some material down there which isn't "soil" at all - e.g. plastic sheets and piles of bricks that the builders just buried to get rid of them. Near where I live in the UK, a neighbour discovered about 200 glass milk bottles buried under a lawn which wasn't growing properly. How they got there is hard to imagine!

Answer (score 0):

Rain can easily fall long and hard enough to produce puddles on any soil. Our area is ancient sand dunes of barrier islands, some organics in a few inches at the surface ,then dune sand to about 10 ft, a couple inches of clay and then more sand below that. . We get puddles in heavy and/or long rains.